# How can i accept RakNet Connecting request in c++?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, server, raknet

I want **accept client's connecting request** but i don't know how can i do this.

## Serverside :

```
enum GameMessages
{
    ID_GAME_MESSAGE_1 = ID_USER_PACKET_ENUM + 1
};

using namespace std;  
int main(void)
{
    RakNet::RakPeerInterface *peer = RakNet::RakPeerInterface::GetInstance();
    bool isServer;
    RakNet::Packet *packet;
    RakNet::SocketDescriptor sd(SERVER_PORT, 0);
    peer->Startup(MAX_CLIENTS, &sd, 1);
    isServer = true;
    if (isServer)
    {
        printf("Sunucu baslatiliyor.\n");
        // We need to let the server accept incoming connections from the clients
        peer->SetMaximumIncomingConnections(MAX_CLIENTS);
    }   
    while (1)
    {
        for (packet = peer->Receive(); packet; peer->DeallocatePacket(packet), packet = peer->Receive())
        {
            switch (packet->data[0])
            {
            case ID_REMOTE_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION:
                printf("Another client has disconnected.\n");
                break;
            case ID_REMOTE_CONNECTION_LOST:
                printf("Another client has lost the connection.\n");
                break;
            case ID_REMOTE_NEW_INCOMING_CONNECTION:
                printf("Another client has connected.\n");
                break;
            case ID_CONNECTION_REQUEST_ACCEPTED:
            {
                printf("Our connection request has been accepted.\n");

                // Use a BitStream to write a custom user message
                // Bitstreams are easier to use than sending casted structures, and handle endian swapping automatically
                RakNet::BitStream bsOut;
                bsOut.Write((RakNet::MessageID)ID_GAME_MESSAGE_1);
                bsOut.Write("Oyuna hosgeldin emmolu.");
                peer->Send(&bsOut, HIGH_PRIORITY, RELIABLE_ORDERED, 0, packet->systemAddress, false);
            }
            break;
            case ID_NEW_INCOMING_CONNECTION:
                printf("Bir baglanti geliyor.\n");
                break;
            case ID_NO_FREE_INCOMING_CONNECTIONS:
                printf("The server is full.\n");
                break;
            case ID_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION:
                if (isServer) {
                    printf("A client has disconnected.\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf("We have been disconnected.\n");
                }
                break;
            case ID_CONNECTION_LOST:
                if (isServer) {
                    printf("A client lost the connection.\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf("Connection lost.\n");
                }
                break;
            case ID_GAME_MESSAGE_1:
            {
                RakNet::RakString rs;
                RakNet::BitStream bsIn(packet->data, packet->length, false);
                bsIn.IgnoreBytes(sizeof(RakNet::MessageID));
                bsIn.Read(rs);
                printf("%s\n", rs.C_String());
            }
            break;
            default:
                printf("Message with identifier %i has arrived.\n", packet->data[0]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    RakNet::RakPeerInterface::DestroyInstance(peer);


    return 0;
}
```

When i try my work it's giving me [image: this].

**[LOG]** 
**Server** : Server started. 
**Client** : Sent request to connect server. 
**Server** : A request received from client to connect server. 
**Server** : Accept client's request. ( What i'm trying to do )

Comment: Editor: please embed image.

Comment: Try asking your question at https://www.slikesoft.com/forum/ and see if anyone can help you with it